# I'm trying to print some pdf files in a directory then move them into another one, but my code only prints the files when I remove the moving part

Tags: c#, printing, process, console-application, move

Here is my code :

```
              //Print & Move the files after printing

        DirectoryInfo sourceinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\fold");
        DirectoryInfo target = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\fold1");
        if (!Directory.Exists(target.FullName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);
        }

        foreach (FileInfo fi in sourceinfo.GetFiles())
        {
            if (fi.Length != 0)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

                process.Refresh();

                //process.StartInfo.Arguments = "EasyCoder 91 DT (203 dpi)";


                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

                process.StartInfo.Verb = "print";

                process.StartInfo.FileName = fi.FullName;
                


                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

                process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

                process.Start();
                

            }






        }
        foreach (FileInfo fi in sourceinfo.GetFiles())
        {
            if (c != 0)
            {
                fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.ToString(), fi.Name), true);
                fi.Delete();
            }






            }
        }
```

I use two foreach loops , the first one prints every file in the directory , the second one moves them to another one but my code only does the moving part , it only prints if I put the moving part in a commentary , can someone please help me?

Comment: English is not my mother tongue and I'm a beginner in C# , can you please be more specific , what do you mean by that?

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't change anything